# Whenever I tried to add a material slot to a tracking scene plane, it shades out black. The File is in **EEVE Mode**

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, render-layers, movie-clip-editor

In **blender version 2.82**, in **EEVE Mode** in rendered shader-view when I tried to add a material slot to a plane, which I generated by tracking a scene, the plane shaded out black with no texture.[image]

I tried it several times but I failed to find a solution to it. Without a material slot it was looking fine but adding a material would turn it black again.[image: It's looking alright without the material]

I thought It's so because I have not added a texture to it. But when I added, It also didn't solve the issue.[image]

**I also even cleared and reassigned UV maps to the plane.** It did not help me.
hope who may be reading this would be knowing the solution to this or may be facing the same problem.
I'll be grateful to the persons who'll be able to find a solution to this.
Hope this information is enough to describe my problem.
I'm also giving a link to the file below--

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bf_9HzR12mw66E9cNw_Tgk2w2oPZX4EM/view?usp=sharing

It will redirect you to my file.

Also I am Giving the link to Image sequence folder below:--

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aaoDAXLmkwhHGHiGpkHfpaX8LX8LNvY5

Also the FPS Rate is 29.97 .

Thanks for trying to understand my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is a simple solution go to your collection and move the ground from background collection to foreground collection

[image]

and the other way is to disable holdout for the background you will find it in the filters in collection

[image]

Comment: Very Very Thanks Mr. Jackson. It Helped me a lot

Comment: Your welcome :)